# Failed to convert String to long when value is null in firebase ( this is meta)

Tags: android

[Hi all, i've database in firebase, but i had error cannot convert Long to string and string to long when a value is null.This is "meta" variable.

1. This is model

   ```
    `public class ModelAnhKhang {
        private String id;
        private String tenhang;
        private String macuon;
        private String dvt;
        private String ngaynhap;
        private String phanloai;
        private Long somet;
        private Long meta;
        private Double tytrong;`
   ```
2. This is Adapter

   ```
    `@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AnhKhangViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final ModelAnhKhang modelAnhKhang = listModelAnhKhang.get(position);
        Locale localeUS = new Locale("us","US");
        NumberFormat us  = NumberFormat.getInstance(localeUS);
        holder.txtMaCuon.setText(modelAnhKhang.getMacuon());
        holder.txtTenHang.setText(modelAnhKhang.getTenhang());
        holder.txtDvt.setText(modelAnhKhang.getDvt());
        holder.txtNgayNhap.setText(modelAnhKhang.getNgaynhap());
        holder.txtSoMet.setText(String.valueOf(us.format(modelAnhKhang.getSomet())));
        holder.txtMetA.setText(String.valueOf(us.format(modelAnhKhang.getMeta())));`
   ```
3. This is Fragment

   ```
    `private void getHangNhapAnhKhang() {
    Query query = reference.child(ANH_KHANG).orderByChild("ngaynhap");
    listModelAnhKhang.clear();
    query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasChildren() || snapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot dss : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        ModelAnhKhang modelAnhKhang = dss.getValue(ModelAnhKhang.class);
                        listModelAnhKhang.add(modelAnhKhang);
                }
            }
            anhKhangAdapter = new AnhKhangAdapter(getContext(), listModelAnhKhang);
            rcv_AnhKhang.setAdapter(anhKhangAdapter);
            anhKhangAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            txtTotal.setText(+anhKhangAdapter.getItemCount()+ " cuộn");
        }`
   ```

4.This is firebase

```
dvt: "Kg"
giaban: 23317.99
khoiluong: 7130
macuon: "00340121080180602"
meta: ""
metb: ""
metc: ""
ngaynhap: "2021/09/06"
phanloai: "L2"
somet: 402
tenhang: "Thép dày mạ kẽm Z275 phủ CR3: 1.80mmx1250mm TCT..."
thanhtien: 166257251
tytrong: 17.736318407960198
```

2. this is firebase
   [1][2]
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8jIo.png
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD6VB.png

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you cannot convert ""(blank) or null to long it is not allowed in java. In your line

```
ModelAnhKhang modelAnhKhang = dss.getValue(ModelAnhKhang.class);
```

you are doing exactly that, passing incompatible values to a variable of type long. If you are using variable "meta" only to show it on some text (which looks like you do), simply change variable meta to String type and your problem will be solved.

If there is some reason why it needs to be of type long then I'd stil suggest the same solution, only where after you pass value from firebase to meta (which is String now) you later pass it to some long type variable while handling "" and null cases.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to pass "null" to a format

```
holder.txtMetA.setText(String.valueOf(us.format(modelAnhKhang.getMeta())));
```

You should handle null values in some way, otherwise java will throw NullPointerExceptions.

Try something like:

```
if(modelAnhKhang.getMeta() != null){
   holder.txtMetA.setText(String.valueOf(us.format(modelAnhKhang.getMeta())));
}else holder.txtMetA.setText("");
```

Comment: Can you show me where you are setting the value of "meta"? (Calling .setMeta(); method)

Comment: public Long getMeta() {
        return meta;
    }

    public void setMeta(Long meta) {
        this.meta = meta;
    }

Comment: I ment the actual call of setMeta method, not its definition. How does the part of your code where you do setMeta(something); look like and what is that something?

Comment: if all of fields has value, no error appear, but one of all null, i have error in :  'ModelAnhKhang modelAnhKhang = dss.getValue(ModelAnhKhang.class);'

Comment: i dont know your mean, that is all my code ''

Comment: Just noticed your error screenshot. It says error trying to convert string TO long, not vice versa, your problem is somewhere else.

My suspicion is the part where meta : "" is being passed to java meta.